# node.js async waterfall call to previous method

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is there anyway we can call to previous method in async.waterfall from a below method.

```
async.waterfall([

        function (callback) {

        },
    function (reservationStatus, callback) {

        },

        function (reservationStatusList, frontOfficeStatusList, callback) {

            callToPreviosFunction();
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        res.json(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

yes We can call the previous function in async.waterfall.
Please look the below modified code.

```
var async = require('async');

async.waterfall([
   a,b,c
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});


function a(callback) {
        console.log("function 1");
        callback(null,"true");
    };
function b(reservationStatus, callback) {
        console.log("function 2");
        callback(null,"true","true");
    };
function c(reservationStatusList, frontOfficeStatusList, callback) {
        console.log("function 3");
        b("confirmed",function(err,result){
            if(err){
                callback(err,null);
            }else{
                callback(null,result);
            }
        }); 
    };
```

As you can see in the above modified code of b()  is again called in c().

Output:

```
function 1
function 2
function 3
function 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Return this from the current function to the next function. It should work

Comment: can you explain it liitle bit.